# Extracting embedded PDF - PDFInterpreterError: Unknown operator: '\x00'

Tags: python, pdf, scrapy, pdfminer

Using Scrapy, I want to download a pdf into read a binary file into memory and extract the contents. I realize that the pdf is embedded in a page that looks like:

```
<embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="http:xxx/DocumentInquiry.aspx?DocumentNo=12502" stream-url="blob:chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/1c86700d-0230-43b1-8b5e-eb219a2220af" headers="Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 50080
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Disposition: inline;filename=DocumentInquiry.pdf
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

When I open the scrapy response.body for http:xxx/DocumentInquiry.aspx?DocumentNo=12502
I see a string that starts with:

```
'%PDF-1.4\n%\xe2\xe3\xcf\xd3\r\n1 0 obj\n<</Type /Page\n/Parent 2 0 R\n/MediaBox [ 0 0 612.000 792.000 ]\n/Resources <</XObject 3 0 R /ProcSet [ /PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ]>>/Contents [ 4 0 R ]\n/Rotate 0\n>>\r\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n<</Type /XObject /Subtype /Image\n/Name /JI1Obj1\n/Width 1275 /Height 1650\n/BitsPerComponent 8\n/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB\n/Filter [ /FlateDecode /DCTDecode ]\n/Length 6 0 R>>\r\nstream\r\nx\x9c\xed\x9dYl\x1bE\x18\x80g}\xa4I\n\x88\xa4[Sh\x11m\xe9\x
```

How do I extract the pdf here ?

edit: I'm using pdfminer with the following function which has worked previously:

```
def convert_pdf_to_html(string):

    in_memory_pdf = BytesIO(
        bytes(string))  # in_memory_pdf IS A FILE LIKE OBJECT SO DOES NOT NEED TO BE OPENED, CLOSED ETC

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = BytesIO()

    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()

    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)  # CONSIDER TextConverter FOR TEXT
    # device = HTMLConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams) # CONSIDER HTMLConverter FOR HTML

    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos = set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(in_memory_pdf, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=caching,
                                  check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    device.close()
    st = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return st
```

I'm getting the following error at the line "for page in PDFPage.get_page...":

```
 File "MypROJEctspiders\forc_spider.py", line 313, in get_order
    full_text = convert_pdf_to_html(response.body)
  File "MypROJEctspiders\forc_spider.py", line 51, in convert_pdf_to_html
    interpreter.process_page(page)
  File "E:\Miniconda2\envs\contact2E\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py", line 834, in process_page
    self.render_contents(page.resources, page.contents, ctm=ctm)
  File "E:\Miniconda2\envs\contact2E\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py", line 846, in render_contents
    self.execute(list_value(streams))
  File "E:\Miniconda2\envs\contact2E\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py", line 876, in execute
    raise PDFInterpreterError('Unknown operator: %r' % name)
PDFInterpreterError: Unknown operator: '\x00'
```

Does this look an error you recognize? I thought that the problem may be the pdf being embedded in the response, and not being parsed correctly by pdfminer.

Comment: sorry to say, no, the times I have used pdfminer I get gray hairs.
So it worked earlier? With same installation, same response.body?

Comment: can you open the pdf if you save to disk? A quick look at the source gives that the error is raised when it does not recognize the method to parse with, so that points towards malformed pdf, or the specific version of miner that you have does not support the pdf-dialect.

Comment: Thanks I switched over to pdfminer.six which appears to be the closest to maintained. I'm not getting the error but I'm also not able to parse my pdf. I'll write a follow up question soon.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
from io import StringIO
file_like = StringIO(your_string)
```

if you're on py3, py2 also has StringIO, but with different import.
if you really have bytes (no b'' in your posted example), there is a analogue BytesIO to use.

For parsing pdf one way is pdfminer, if you're on py3 there is a version called pdfminer-six that is possible to get running.
Plenty of so examples of how to use pdfminer.
However pending on the actual pdf and what you are looking for in the pdf you might get gray hairs before you are able to pull it out in an acceptable and reproducible way for later use.

If you can't find a stream-reader in pdfminer it will probably work to write the string to disk and then you have your pdf-file on disk as starting point for pdfminer.